# What are the steps to re-initailize Hyperledger Blockchain demo

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I installed a Hyperledger [development environment](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html) and am considering deleting the blockchain data to start from scratch. What would be the steps to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete you containers volumes.

1) First stop the containers:

> ./stopFabric.sh

2) Delete containers volumes:

> docker volume rm [volume id]

3) Start again the fabric environment

> ./startFabric.sh

You can check you volumes using:

> docker volume ls

Comment: thx,  to be sure: "docker volume ls" shows 9 volumes, which of them need to be deleted, all?

Comment: You can check the volume associated with your container using this command:
**docker container inspect -f '{{.Mounts}}' [CONTAINER NAME] | grep volume**
Use **docker container ls --all** to get the name of the stopped containers

Comment: These are the containers: dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.0.1,  peer0.org1.example.com, couchdb, orderer.example.com, ca.org1.example.com. The volumes of what container needs to be removed so startFabric.sh will function as advised above?

Comment: Delete all, the idea is begin from scratch. When you start the fabric environment, it will be create the volume again